# trying to set a number of questions based on user input and then stop the code and return score

Tags: python, math, while-loop

At the moment the code runs for an infinite amount of questions and never stops unless you select the exit option I included in but I want to get rid of it so it solely relies on the amount of questions the user inputs. I know I need a while loops but I don't know how to install it properly. Please help here is the code.

```
import random

def display_intro():
    title = "** A Simple Math Quiz **"
    print("*" * len(title))
    print(title)
    print("*" * len(title))


def display_menu():
    print("Choose your difficulty !")
    menu_list = ["1. Easy", "2. Hard", "3. Spicy", "4. Exit"]
    print(menu_list[0])
    print(menu_list[1])
    print(menu_list[2])
    print(menu_list[3])

def get_user_input():
    user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    while user_input > 4 or user_input <= 0:
        print("Invalid menu option.")
        user_input = int(input("Please try again: "))
    else:
        return user_input

def num_questions():
   total_questions = int(input("How many questions would you like?: "))
    while total_questions >= 0 and total_questions < 100:
        print("Lets Go!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Please Try Again")

def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result


def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count,):

    if user_solution == solution:
        count = count + 1
        print("Correct.")
        return count
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        return count

def menu_option(index, count):
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 9)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 9)
    number_three = random.randrange(10, 99)
    number_four = random.randrange(10, 99)
    number_five = random.randrange(100, 999)
    number_six = random.randrange(100, 999)

    if index is 1:
        problem = str(number_one) + " * " + str(number_two)
        solution = number_one * number_two
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count
    elif index is 2:
        problem = str(number_three) + " * " + str(number_four)
        solution = number_three * number_four
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count
    elif index is 3:
        problem = str(number_five) + " * " + str(number_six)
        solution = number_five * number_six
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count

def display_result(total, correct):
    if total > 0:
        result = correct / total
        percentage = round((result * 100), 2)
    if total == 0:
        percentage = 0
    print("You answered", total, "questions with", correct, "correct.")
    print("Your score is ", percentage, "%. Thank you.", sep = "")


def main():
    display_intro()
    num_questions()
    display_menu()

    option = get_user_input()
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    while option != 4:
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)
        option = get_user_input()

    print("Exit the quiz.")
    display_result(total, correct)

main()
```

Comment: Looks to be a copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64177239/238704) question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `num_questions()` return the user input so you can use it in your main function:

```
def num_questions():
   total_questions = int(input("How many questions would you like?: "))
   while total_questions >= 0 and total_questions < 100:
       print("Lets Go!")
       return total_questions
       break
   else:
        print ("Please Try Again")
```

Then you can rework your main function and do something like this (there are comments in the key changes):

```
def main():
    display_intro()
    total_questions = num_questions() # save amount of questions
    display_menu()

    total = 0
    correct = 0
    while total < total_questions: # keep going until total is reached
        option = get_user_input() # get input at the beginning of loop
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)

    print("Exit the quiz.")
    display_result(total, correct)
```

The loop is changed so it keeps going until it reaches the amount of questions the user selected. Note that the way we get input is also changed.

If you still want to give the user the ability to exit by entering 4, you can do something like this:

```
    while total < total_questions:
        option = get_user_input()
        if option == 4: # check if user entered 4
            break
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)
```

---

Full code:

```
import random

def display_intro():
    title = "** A Simple Math Quiz **"
    print("*" * len(title))
    print(title)
    print("*" * len(title))


def display_menu():
    print("Choose your difficulty !")
    menu_list = ["1. Easy", "2. Hard", "3. Spicy", "4. Exit"]
    print(menu_list[0])
    print(menu_list[1])
    print(menu_list[2])
    print(menu_list[3])

def get_user_input():
    user_input = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    while user_input > 4 or user_input <= 0:
        print("Invalid menu option.")
        user_input = int(input("Please try again: "))
    else:
        return user_input

def num_questions():
   total_questions = int(input("How many questions would you like?: "))
   while total_questions >= 0 and total_questions < 100:
       print("Lets Go!")
       return total_questions
       break
   else:
        print ("Please Try Again")

def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result


def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count,):

    if user_solution == solution:
        count = count + 1
        print("Correct.")
        return count
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        return count

def menu_option(index, count):
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 9)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 9)
    number_three = random.randrange(10, 99)
    number_four = random.randrange(10, 99)
    number_five = random.randrange(100, 999)
    number_six = random.randrange(100, 999)

    if index is 1:
        problem = str(number_one) + " * " + str(number_two)
        solution = number_one * number_two
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count
    elif index is 2:
        problem = str(number_three) + " * " + str(number_four)
        solution = number_three * number_four
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count
    elif index is 3:
        problem = str(number_five) + " * " + str(number_six)
        solution = number_five * number_six
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        count = check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
        return count

def display_result(total, correct):
    if total > 0:
        result = correct / total
        percentage = round((result * 100), 2)
    if total == 0:
        percentage = 0
    print("You answered", total, "questions with", correct, "correct.")
    print("Your score is ", percentage, "%. Thank you.", sep = "")


def main():
    display_intro()
    total_questions = num_questions()
    display_menu()

    total = 0
    correct = 0
    while total < total_questions:
        option = get_user_input()
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)

    print("Exit the quiz.")
    display_result(total, correct)

main()
```

Comment: okay this is making sense but im slightly confused as to how to make num_question() return user_input in your 1st  part of what you said?

Comment: My bad, I copied and pasted the wrong function! I've edited my answer now. What I meant to include in the first part of my answer was the `num_questions()` function, where I've added a return statement. Please check it out and let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: No problem!  yeah its working great now thank you very much